# Most practical isometric tile, or does it even matter?

Tags: tiles, isometric

I am asking for the most practical/convenient isometric tile. I have seen a lot of tiles, some like this (you have to zoom in somehow to see the pixels, sorry):

[image]

[image]

I know there are different types of isometric, but I am asking for the best one for games, not the most realistic one. Please ask further questions if something is not clear.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What you mean — a practical tile?

Comment: @psycketom I was wondering about the ratios of width and height. I decided to go with a ratio of 2:1 (width is 2x the height), since a lot of algorithms seem to support that. Also it is easier to get them to match with an exact ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't matter. Choose the one you want to work with and work with it. How you display the world is only a small part of the game, and if done correctly, can easily be changed later on if you find it's inconvenient or not the style you want.

Comment: Sure. It's important not to get hung up on the details. Things can always be fixed later if needed. Typically it's more important to just make a decision and move forward.